# handle static file-paths with specified controller in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have this map-route in my global:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "SiteMap",
        "sitemap.xml",
        new { controller = "Feed", action = "SiteMap" }
        );
```

in local, it works, but on the server doesn't! how can I force the server to pass this url-requests to my application? my server is IIS 7.5 and i can remote to iis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer myself! thanks to all;
in web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add url="~/sitemap.xml" mappedUrl="~/Feed/SiteMap"/>
    </urlMappings>
  </system.web>
```